# ProgressBar does not appear in WebView located in Fragment ,how to show ProgressBar in WebView android?

Tags: java, android, webview, progress-bar, visibility

Whenever, I enter the fragment, I am shown a blank space for a few seconds, then the webpage in the WebView shows up. It seems that the ProgressBar does not show.

Here's my XML file for the Fragment the WebView and ProgressBar is in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".FragmentThree">

    <ProgressBar

        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Java file for the Fragment Java implementation:

```
package com.example.task1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class FragmentThree extends Fragment {
    private WebView webView;
    private String URL;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentThree(String url) {
        // Required empty public constructor
        this.URL = url;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);
        initMain(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initMain(View view) {
        webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        progressBar.setMax(100);
        webView.loadUrl(URL);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });

    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

The code is mostly located under the initMain() function for clarification.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you for reading!

Comment: try putting the progressbar below the webview in the xml, otherwise the webview will be above the progressbar and cover it.

Comment: @JoachimHaglund oh my god. EDIT: Also thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare `ProgressBar` below `Webview` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".FragmentThree">



    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </WebView>
    <ProgressBar

        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yup, just did so from the comment above. Thank you for answering however! It's my fault for being careless.